# xslt 2.0 remove spaces from string-to-codepoints

Tags: xslt-2.0

I am generating an ID using generate-id(), I convert this ID into a numbers using string-to-codepoints.

How can I remove the spaces from the resulting number?

So e.g. the resulting codepoints are "17 28 39 28", but I need "17283928".

Translate doesn't work, because it expects a string. And I cant convert the number to a string, because string() cannot handle the spaces.

How can I achieve this?

Comment: Can you show us some sample code, `string-to-codepoints` would give you a sequence of `xs:integer` numbers. What are you doing with the sequence when you say you get `17 28 39 28`? If you use `<xsl:variable name="s" select="string-join(string-to-codepoints(generate-id()), '')"/> `, then you should have a string. If you use `value-of`, then simply set e.g. `<xsl:value-of select="string-to-codepoints(generate-id())" separator=""/>`.

Comment: You already answered the question. I can use xsl:value-of... I used the string-to-codepoints(generate-id()) in an attribute value template. But the xsl:value-of converts it into a string automatically, I didnt even think of that!! Thanks a lot!

Comment: I have put my suggestions and an improvement based on your explanation of the use of an attribute value template into an answer so that you can mark your question as being solved.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on your comment, you used `string-to-codepoints(generate-id())` in an attribute value template, in an attribute value template if the expression evaluates to a sequence then a space separated list of values of the sequence is inserted. You either need to use `string-join` on the sequence to construct a single string or you need to construct the string outside of an attribute value template, as `<xsl:value-of select="string-to-codepoints(generate-id())" separator=""/>` allows.

Here is an example using `string-join`:

```
<xsl:template match="foo">
    <bar id="{string-join(for $n in string-to-codepoints(generate-id()) return string($n), '')}" />
</xsl:template>
```

which will construct a result element alike `<bar id="1004910149"/>` without spaces in the attribute value.

Comment: Great! I keep forgetting this new XPath syntax even exists :D Thanks!

Comment: You can simplify this to `id="{string-join(string-to-codepoints(generate-id()))}"` in XSLT 3.0.

Answer (score 0):

(Not an answer but too long for a comment).

Interesting supplementary: does this algorithm guarantee unique keys?

Could there be two distinct strings such that the function `string-join(string-to-codepoints($x)!string(), '')` produces the same string of digits?

I think you're in luck, because `generate-id()` is guaranteed to produce strings consisting only of ASCII alphanumeric characters. This means that all the characters must have codepoints in the range 48 to 122, which means that every codepoint converts to either 2 or 3 digits, and by looking at the first digit you can tell whether it's a 2-digit or 3-digit sequence.

Before I worked this out, I was going to suggest that you pad the codepoints with zeroes to make all the sequences uniform length.

Comment: Regarding the padding: Would it be possible in XSLT to alter generate-id() in such a way that you can specify the number of characters? E.g. make a function generate-id(14) that gives you a unique id with 14 characters?

Comment: If you can come up with an algorithm then I'm sure it can be coded in XSLT; but I can't immediately think of an efficient algorithm.

Comment: I was rather thinking that generate-id should bring this behaviour with it. I dont know how Saxon implements this function, but in Java it is possible to generate a random alphanumeric string of fixed length, isnt it?

Comment: I don't know any Java method that generates a random string of fixed length, but such a method would be of little use, since a sequence of random strings will in general contain duplicates, and the essence of generate-id() is that there are no duplicates.